# ASP.NET 1.1 issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason I cannot add a server control onto a specific asp.net form. If I make an attempt to do this, I get the following error when selecting from the datagrid: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

I have checked the values and they are all non negative and this exact select works if I restore the page back to the original form from source control.

How do server controls affect the index property of a datagrid?

here is where the code fails:

```
int _indiv;
int _index;
index = e.Item.ItemIndex;
indiv = Convert.ToInt32(
            (grd_associateSearch.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]).ToString());
```

I cannot get past the last line with an additional server control on the page and the code works flwlessly without it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break down that line into logical steps to find out where the error comes from? It is likely from  `grd_associateSearch.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]`.